# Crawled Property with accountname of "Person or Group" Site Column in SharePoint 2010

Tags: content-type, crawling, site-column, managed-property

I created a custom content type that includes a custom site column "Owner" of type "Person or Group". Now i need the accountname/login name (for exc. domain\usera) as a crawled property to include it in a managed property. The problem is that there is only a crawled property "ows_Owner(text)"that includes the display name (for exc. User A). Shouldn't there be also a crawled property that contains the account name ? 
Is there a way to get the crawled property that contains the accountname ?
(Note: I already created a list from the content type, including items, and did a full crawl with the search service app).

thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the full domain and login name directly this way. Think about what kind of security risks that could cause. I don't have experience with the crawl properties, but I solved a similar issue with the object model.

Perhaps this post will help:

[CSOM Query on Hidden User Information List returning nothing](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33849/csom-query-on-hidden-user-information-list-returning-nothing)

You can't expose the domain and login, but you can get the ID.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer! you might be right that it is not possible to get the full domain and login name directly. But The ID  would also be enough... 
Its strange if it doesent work, because the standard "AssingedTo" Site Column gets crawled with an account ID!